# Restrict generic parameter to specify the only property it has and build internally

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to write a function that create instances of object.
I know that the built objects will have just one field, but *both* the name of the property and the type of the value associated to it should be set "dynamically" (it's enough if I can specify the property name using constants).

I tried to play with generics and restrictions but I don't really understand them.

```js
// the goal: create an object with a property that is an 1-element array
function factory<TContainer, TElement>(key: string, element: TElement): TContainer {
    return {[key]: [element]};
}
```

```js
// how I want to use it

// given a type
type T1 = {
    key1: number[];
};

// instead of
const e1a: T1 = { key1: [1]};
const e1b: T1 = { key1: [1, 2]};
const e1c: T1 = { key1: []};

// I want to write
const e1z: T1 = factory<T1, number>('key1', 999); // e1z === {key1: [999]};
const e2z: T2 = factory<T2, string>('key2', 'z'); // e2z === {key2: ['z']};

// moreover I want also to use it without explicit types
const onthefly:{onthefly:string[]} = factory<{onthefly:string[]}, string>('onthefly', 'onthefly'); // onthefly === {onthefly: ['onthefly']};

// even better if the compiler knew what the types will be without telling him
const magic = factory('magic', 3); // magic:{magic:number[]} === {magic:[3]}
```

but all I get are errors like

```
Type '{ [x: string]: TElement[]; }' is not assignable to type 'TContainer'.
      'TContainer' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ [x: string]: TElement[]; }'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3gKCpqBrCI4BcUAdgK4C2ARhAE4DaAugNxoC+LaoksATEqhiy4QPIgGdgNAJbEA5oxas0aAMYB7YhKgQ4AQyLx+KHHkJQ6cBu1UatOygYTJjwsxYA0UHlZbrNwbTgVRyMTfCJGaxt-bR59XlDhUXMAcl0Un2i7HgcE5zDkuhTKFM8UlQzrP2zgvNQCiMy0ADNSYhVgKQ0oZt0OtRoQAB4YAGENYF0ZWk8YAFEAGwhyCGJgAD4ACmFxSRlZTwgllbWDReXV4ABKA3G1qeJaASwoGghgUhpiVDphBgijhc1pklFkAjoAF4hZC9fqDEZwTxkKi0LYpVylKAAThxVyYUAA9ATAhCkIhnK4IjisZlquCeFC6rDgANhjAeJ4JNI5GikpiUhCUnjCcSIAyyRS8IUBZUOHSoBMABYQZoLEAEFBKlVqghc-aRfjM1lDTVrZWq9V6uSRTl7HmbFJai38p1qoX4okKs3akAS1Cu9WpAOy5Ty8i6WRSFSGvoswYO8ORiqeADMws9iajGszwWR1HoVj9KBzBDoKasaCAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the `factory` function like this:

```
function factory<K extends string, V>(key: K, element: V) {
    return { [key]: [element] } as { [Key in K]: [V] };
}
```

Now we actually use both generic types as arguments so they can be properly inferred. `K` holds the key of the resulting object while `V` holds the value type.

Calling the function will result in the following types:

```
const e1z = factory('key1', 999); // { key1: [number] };
const e2z = factory('key2', 'z'); // { key2: [string] };
const onthefly = factory('onthefly', 'onthefly'); // { onthefly: [string] };
const magic = factory('magic', 3); // { magic: [number] }
```

You may notice here that the types are widened. So `999` becomes just `number`. Let me know if this is ok for you. There are more complicated solutions which will narrow down the type further.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3gKCpqBrCI4BcUAdgK4C2ARhAE4DaAugNxoC%20LaoksATEqhiy4QPIgGdgNAJbEA5oxas0aAMYB7YhKgQ4AQyLx%20KHHkJQ6cBu1UatOygYTJjwsxYA0UHlZbrNwbTgVRyMTfCJGaxt-bR59XlDhUXMAcl0Un2i7HgcE5zDkuhTKFM8UlQzrP2zgvNQCiMy0ADNSYhVgKQ0oZt0OtRoQAB4AaW0AD2AIYgATMSgJaTlPADUAPgAKYSIRzwgAGwhyaeAiFYBKASwoGghgUhpierphBgiDo5OGKFYoXXnjHQRngoDIoCM3uYVt9rEosgEdAAvfi9fqDDYpVylKAATjx5yYUAA9ETAsjEBT6q4ImQqLQYb5bAieOSen1gAMQBiktiUoiUgTiaSICykJSXHhCosZLIGfCoBpgAALCDNfYgFHszkYxUqtUgXm61XqgWEkkK4jK40ain5I36iLSuRy6oBci6WRSFSatFclLuz0VTwAZkF5oDXoIxgjwVp1HoMLF%20RjNIo8ZhaCAA)